# Access http-only or secure cookies on Android devices React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm current build a RN app with `react-native-webview` and `@react-native-community/cookies`.
Now, i need to access all cookies in webview. With some help of `@react-native-community/cookies` on ios devices, i can get all of this but on android i only get non-secure/non-httpOnly cookies.

Android devices is running on API 28.

Here my code:

1. Implement webview

```js
          <WebView
            ref={webViewRef}
            source={{uri: 'https://example.com'}}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
            thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
          />
```

2. Get cookies

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    let getCookies = () =>
      CookieManager.getAll(useWebKit).then((cookies) => {
        console.log('CookieManager.get =>', cookies);
      });

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      getCookies = () =>
        CookieManager.get('https://linkedin.com').then((cookies) => {
          console.log('CookieManager.get =>', cookies);
        });
    }

    getCookies();
  }, [url]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Did you find a solution ? I have the same issue, I am not finding the same cookie on iOS and Android...

Answer (score -1):

Try: `CookieManager.setAccessCookie(true)`

Comment: Property 'setAccessCookie' does not exist on type 'CookieManagerStatic'. :(